# Complex Active Record Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

```
User
  first_name: "Johnny"
  age: 15

Car
  name: "Mazda"

Car
  name: "BMW"
```

I would like results that look like

```
[ {"first_name": "Johnny", "age": 15, cars: [ { "name": "Mazda" }, { "name" : "BMW" } ] } ]
```

Is it possible to do this in Rails? So far I can get the Users car by typing `johnny.cars` but I'd like the data structure to also hold the values of the `parent`.

I was toying with the idea of using named_scopes and transient attributes but no luck so far any ideas/help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: what your model assoications between car ans user `has_many` or `has_many :through` may then we can help also are looking to return json output from server then I guess then this link can help `http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Serialization/to_json`

Comment: I am using many-to-many (has many through) but I'd like to loop on all of the Users whilst displaying all of their Cars.

Comment: so what stopping you then didnt you try :includes =>  :cars when fetch all User something like this `User.includes(:cars)`

Comment: I am new to rails let me try that first :)

Comment: Oww it actually works, you should post that as answer so that I can accept it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Could actually retrieve all the records from the other table using `:includes` statement

`includes` is magically syntax where in you can eager load all the assocaited records of a record.

Example In your case

User has_many cars

so If you do

`@users = User.includes(:cars)`

Now this would load **all** the user records and will eagerload all the cars records for each user objects

so if you loop through a user object and do

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <%= user.cars %>
<%end%>
```

`user.cars` wont fire a seperate query to fetch the all cars for the users instead it will fetch those record eager loaded using the `includes` clause

This technique is widely used to avoid `N+1` query problem

Google for `N+1` to know more on it

Hope this Help